# Jobs beta does not respect zip code selection

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

On the Jobs beta tab, if I do a search for a specific zip code, it displays results from all over the country instead.  Is this a bug?

Go to https://stackoverflow.com/jobs, type in 93010 (Camarillo CA) in the Location field and set Distance to 20 miles, leave the Keywords field empty, and press Search.  It shows **2313 jobs near Camarillo, CA**, with results from many states including CA, CO, NY, TX, even a few results from *Berlin, Deutschland*!  Nothing that is anywhere near 20 miles from 93010.

Comment: Unable to reproduce; exact steps?

Comment: I updated my question with steps.

Comment: Still unable to reproduce; I only got 2 results.  Either its been fixed, or it is so far limited to you.

Comment: My SO Careers e-mails (which just send daily updates of job search results) two days ago just started showing everything from the US as "within 20 km of Europe" and also "within 100 km of Switzerland".  And, in fact, I can confirm a manual search shows something from Texas for "100 km from Bern, Switzerland", and the same job is there for within 20 km.

Comment: I can confirm this bug in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Works as expected in Lynx, though. @Daedalus : what browser are you using?

Comment: @MikeBaranczak Chrome version 47.0.2526.106 m.

Comment: I'm using IE11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the report, Remy. We've had a problem with job search over the last 48 hours that I just deployed a fix for. It should be fixed now (I just show the two jobs in Camarillo).

Comment: Works as expected now. Thanks for fixing.